# DynamoDB GSI - Only include some rows

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is there a way with DynamoDB to only include some rows in the Global Secondary Index? For example, I want to have a list of all things that have ever happened with an attribute which indicates if it's active. If it is active, I want it to show up in the GSI, but if it's not active, it doesn't need to be projected at all. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

GSI is a sparse index, which means if the defined Partition and Sort keys for the GSI do not exist on the item, it will not exist in the GSI.

Additionally, keep in mind Partition Key and Sort Key in a GSI don't need to be unique like the base table. Uniqueness isn't enforced for GSI

Not knowing your data model, you could use an attribute which only exists on active items in the Key Schema for the GSI.

This might provide some more information: https://www.abhayachauhan.com/2017/12/dynamodb-global-secondary-indexes

HTH

Answer (score 2):

From my testing, it seems that you can use null as a range key and rows without that attribute will not be projected.